# Any Java caches that can limit memory usage of in-memory cache, not just instance count?

Tags: java, caching, memory-management, ehcache

I am looking for a simple in-memory (and in-process) cache for short-term caching of query data (but short-term meaning beyond request/response, i.e. session boundary).
EhCache would probably work, but it looks as if it might not offer one thing that I need: limits not on number of objects cached, but (approximate) limit on amount of memory consumed by cached data.

I understand that it is hard to figure out exact memory usage for given object without serialization (which I want to avoid in general case due to its slowness defeats the purpose for my uses), and I am fine with having to provide size estimate myself.

So: is there a simple open source java cache that allows for defining "weight" of cached objects, to limit amount of things cached?

EDIT (Nov 2010): For what it's worth, there is a new project called [Java CacheMate](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-cachemate) that tries to tackle this issue, along with some other improvement ideas (multi-level in-memory in-process caching)

Comment: Hmmh. I must have written my question badly, since most answers focus on parts that are not problematic for me. I am fine with providing useful estimation -- I just need cache to make use of it. That is, not JUST number of objects, but also total weight. I guess none of 'standard' ones do this.

Comment: I think a bit more detail of what you need would be helpful. Is the *only* factor you want to be taken into consideration the (static) weight of the item? Presumably you want a total "weight" the cache can support as well.. what about timing? Should that come into play at all?

Comment: May I asked why do you need a size-based cache?

Comment: Yes: just the static weight. I understand that there are many factors that would be useful and interesting: I am fine ignoring them here. Freshness could matter, but LRU is fine here as well.

And size-based is to limit amount of heap cache uses.

Thanks for all answers, comments, hope this helps!

Comment: As to why size-based: to ensure memory usage of cache and contents is bounded (within limits of proper approximation) -- I may want to allocate about 100 megs for one cache, 200 for another one, with total max heap of, say, 1 gig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Paul that this is often solved by using a soft reference cache, though it may evict entries earlier than you prefer. A usually acceptable solution is to use a normal cache that evicts to the soft cache, and recovers entries on a miss if possible. This victim caching approach works pretty well, giving you a lower bar but extra benefit if free memory is available.

The memory size can be determined by enabling the Java agent, and usage is pretty simple when using the SizeOf utility (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sizeof). I've only used this for debugging purposes, and I'd recommend benchmarking the overhead before adopting it for normal usage.

In my caching library, I am planning on adding the ability to plug in a evaluator once the core algorithm is implemented. This way you could store a collection as the value, but bound the cache by the sum of all collection sizes. I have seen unbounded collections as values in caches cause OutOfMemoryExceptions, so having control is quite handy.

If you really need this, and I'd advise not to, we could enhance my current implementation to support this. You can email me, ben.manes-at-gmail.com.

Comment: This actually sounds like something that could work once you add it.
Like I said, I don't need exact usage; I can easily figure out approximate costs for byte[]s and such. I just need to have a cache that can make use of just weights.

Comment: Please email me so we can talk about this more. I believe you could decorate a LinkedHashMap for this without much difficulty. Doing so would resolve a race concern I'd have to resolve since I am not using a giant lock to guard the entire structure. So I'd prefer pushing this feature off for now...

Answer (score 3):

How about using a simple LinkedHashMap with LRU algorithm enabled and put all data with a SoftReference in it... such as cache.out(key, new SoftReference(value)) ??

This would limit your cache to the amount of available memory but not kill the rest of your programm, because Java removes the soft references when there is a memory demand... not all.. the oldest first... usually. If you add a reference queue to your implementation, you can also remove the stall entries (only key, no value) from the map.

This would free you from calculating the size of the entries and keeping track of the sum.

Comment: It's not really a good idea to use Softrefernces for cache implementations. At least not in an app server. The reason is that you cannot really control very well how long they live.

Comment: Well, it depends on your needs. Usually a cache needs only limited predictability. A LRU algorithm backed by an emergency value in case we are low in memory is not too bad. 

You can improve that with a two level cache... hard references first, soft after some time.

Comment: the point is that the live time of Softreferences only depends on the free memory of the app server. You cannot control it independently per application.

Comment: Why should I control it? This is the nice part, that I can use the memory I have for caching (hence the word caching) and if I do not have the memory... hey, I have to recalc things.

Comment: Yes, If you have a single user desktop application that might work. But on an app server you could end up with several applications competing for the available memory and you cannot control how much each gets.

Comment: You control the max with the Xmx setting. On an appserver, there are always many applications which compete. The trick is to find out, whether you want to trade memory for speed or vise versa.

Comment: I agree in that soft references are perfectly fine and nice for many things; but not for use case I am thinking. There will be multiple caches, and I do want stricter control on actual memory usage; and not using soft or weak references (plus TTL) this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

EhCache V2.5 currently offers a solution which can cap based on the memory size of the cache. For more details checkout [EhCache 2.5 Documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/configuration#memory-based-cache-sizing-ehcache-25-and-higher)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, it's a useful addition.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just hard to measure - it's hard to define.

Suppose two cache entries refer to the same string - do they *both* count the size of that string, despite the fact that removing either of them from the cache wouldn't make the string eligible for garbage collection? Do neither of them count the size, despite the fact that if *both* of them are removed from the cache the string may then be eligible for collection? What about if another object not in the cache has a reference to that string?

If you can accurately describe the size you're interested in it *may* be possible to ascertain it programmatically - but I suspect you'll find it's hard even to decide exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi Jon,
Your comment makes sense overall, but there's a meaningful way to compute the size of the cache (retained size). See my answer below.

Comment: I am not interested in generic solution -- for my use case, yes, I can very easily determine approximate size.
I agree that in generic case it is of course impossible. That's fine, I don't need to solve that problem. :)

Comment: Okay, so you want weighting by size. Do you also want weighting by last time used as well? How do you want those to balance? Without the last time element, you could use a PriorityQueue alongside a HashMap, to work out what to evict. Keep a total as well so you know when to evict.

Comment: For me, priorization on what to evict, and total bounds for cache can remain separate concerns; LRU is fine, even if it means that one big item was to consume whole cache "quota". So yes, I agree, keeping separate ordering & queues make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As well as guessing the memory usage of the object, for a reasonable algorithm you would also need to guess the cost of recreating it. A reasonable guess would be the cost of recreation is roughly proportional to memory size. So the factors cancel each other out and you need neither. A simple algorithm is probably going to work out better.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot make any estimations - write a cache eviction policy which flushes based on the JVM heap size (polled from System) or triggered by a finalize()-call from an orphaned object (on GC).

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to define a meaningful measure for the memory usage of a cache. You could compute the : ["retained size"](http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-really-measure-memory-usage-of.html). 
Unfortunately computing the retained size is roughly as costly as a full GC, and it's therefore probably not an option. In certain JVM languages (clojure?) you could theoretically make sure that no objects in the cache would be referenced from outside objects and then you could monitor the real size of the cache.

Comment: However, that measure doesn't take account of the fact that pushing either one of two entries out of the cache might free almost no space, but pushing *both* out might free a very large amount.

Comment: Hi Jon,
You just need to compute the "retained set" for the whole cache. You simulate that the cache "root" object (assume for now it's one), could be removed from memory, you run a simulated full GC and then you count which objects would be reclaimed.

Answer (score -1):

The thing that does this job is java.lang.ref.SoftReference . Typically, you extend the SoftReference class so that the subclass contains the key.