# How to remove elements from map if it reaches a memory size limit?

Tags: java, caching, memory-management, guava, lru

I have implemented a LRU cache using `ConcurrentLinkedHashMap`. In the same map, I am purging events if my map reaches a particular limit as shown below.

I have a `MAX_SIZE` variable which is equivalent to 3.7 GB and as soon as my map reaches that limit, I am purging events from my map.

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.ConcurrentLinkedHashMap;
import com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap.EvictionListener;

// does this really equal to 3.7 GB? can anyone explain this?
public static final int MAX_SIZE = 20000000; //equates to ~3.7GB with assumption that each event is 200 bytes AVG

public static EvictionListener<String, DataObject> listener = new EvictionListener<String, DataObject>() {
    public void onEviction(String key, DataObject value) {
        deleteEvents();
    }
};
public static final ConcurrentMap<String, DataObject> holder = new ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.Builder<String, DataObject>()
            .maximumWeightedCapacity(MAX_SIZE).listener(listener).build();

private static void deleteEvents() {
    int capacity = MAX_SIZE - (MAX_SIZE * (20 / 100));
    if (holder.size() >= capacity) {
        int numEventsToEvict = (MAX_SIZE * 20) / 100;
        int counter = 0;
        Iterator<String> iter = holder.keySet().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext() && counter < numEventsToEvict) {
            String address = iter.next();
            holder.remove(address);
            System.out.println("Purging Elements: " +address);
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

// this method is called every 30 seconds from a single background thread 
// to send data to our queue
public void submit() {
    if (holder.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    // some other code here

    int sizeOfMsg = 0;
    Iterator<String> iter = holder.keySet().iterator();
    int allowedBytes = MAX_ALLOWED_SIZE - ALLOWED_BUFFER;

    while (iter.hasNext() && sizeOfMsg < allowedBytes) {
        String key = iter.next();
        DataObject temp = holder.get(key);

        // some code here

        holder.remove(key);

        // some code here to send data to queue
    }
}   

// this holder map is used in below method to add the events into it.
// below method is being called from some other place.
public void addToHolderRequest(String key, DataObject stream) {
    holder.put(key, stream);
}
```

Below is the maven dependency I am using for this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap</groupId>
    <artifactId>concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure whether this is the right way to do this? Does this `MAX_SIZE` really equates to 3.7 GB if events are of 200 bytes in average? Is there any better way to do this? I also have a background thread which call `deleteEvents()` method every 30 second and same background thread also calls `submit` method to extract data from `holder` map and send to queue.

So idea is, add events to `holder` map in `addToHolderRequest` method and then from the background every 30 second call `submit` method which will send data to our queue by iterating this map and then after submit method is finished, call `deleteEvents()` method from same background thread which will purge elements. I am running this code in production and it looks like it is not purging events properly and my holder map size keeps growing. I have a min/max heap memory set as 6GB.

Comment: Java object size on the heap is very tricky and error prone to measure. I'd be suspicious if the assumption of 200 bytes average held true, depending on how it was calculated. It seems odd that your listener tries to purge the map, which seems redundant. A massive cache also suffers from GC effects, such as all entries being promoted and may require a more expensive (e.g. STW) collection. What alternative to recommend, though, is dependent on your application.

Comment: @BenManes What should I do then? In my case I just need to start reemoving elements from the map if it reaches a particular memory limit? Or I can have limit on number of elements in the map but that number of elements in the map should be less than heap memory size which is set as 6GB as of now. If that assumption was not true then how do I calculate it then? Idea is, I don't want my `holder` map to keep growing and eventually run out of memory so just start removing oldest elements from the LRU cache. Btw, I am on Java 7.

Comment: The only measure of how much is retained is after a full GC.  Otherwise you don't know how much would be retained if a Full GC was run.  Obviously you have to include all the memory used per entry which includes the Map.Entry, the size of the key and it's object header and the size of the values and it's object header.  This can easily be about 64 bytes or more.

Comment: Using an Iterator on a ConcurrentHastMap is a very poor way to evict entries. The iterator will start with the same segment and so you will be deleting from the first segment(s) while the last segment might never have entries evicted.  You are better off removing entries at random. Ideally you would use a queue of entries to remove.  A simpler strategy is to have more than one ConcurrentHashMap old and new for example.  Only add to the new and when the map is half full drop the old and add a new "new" map.  You could use 4 maps so you only ever drop 1/4 of the entries on a clean up.

Comment: @PeterLawrey hmmm few things I didn't understand very well because of my limited understanding about segments in cache. Could you provide an example by which I can understand and what is the best way to solve my problem here?

Comment: @user1950349 ConcurrentHashMap works cocnurrently because it uses a number of segments which can be accessed independently. It is like an array of Maps where each map is single threaded however there should be so many segments that on average threads rarely try to access the same segment.  If you always remove using an Iterator, you keep clearing segment 0 but never clear the later segments regardless of age.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks, this segment thing is clear now. Appreciated for explaining but I want to know it more, if you can provide some link where this is explained better, I would like to learn more about it. Now when you say iterator is poor choice, what else I should use. In your earlier comment you mentioned to use four maps which I am not sure how it will work.

Comment: @user1950349 You use a map for the latest values, map for the the second oldest values, a map for third oldest and finally the map you are about to discard.  When the maps get too full, discard the oldest map and shuffle them down. This way you can discard the oldest 1/4 of entries in one go. You could even hold the oldest map  in a WeakReference so the GC will discard them.

Comment: @PeterLawrey CLHM uses the CHMv8 backport in later releases, so the segment issue is now RB trees instead. The map has an LRU iterator, but its more costly to construct.

Comment: @user1950349 Feel free to email me with details on your application's use-case and we can discuss. I tend to prefer to rely on the data store (db, redis, etc) and have lightweight servers. For analytics that may not work, though a simple hack of a local database/search engine often works surprisingly well. These can be better than an [off-heap cache](https://github.com/snazy/ohc) because you send queries to limit the result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In lieu of estimating the size of objects in the JVM and referencing them using strong references you can use soft references which are "most often used to implement memory-sensitive caches" ([SoftReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html)). e.g. [CacheBuilder.softValues()](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html#softValues()) from [google/guava: Google Core Libraries for Java 6+](https://github.com/google/guava): "Softly-referenced objects will be garbage-collected in a *globally* least-recently-used manner, in response to memory demand." However, I'd recommend first familiarizing yourself with [CachesExplained · google/guava Wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) (specifically the [Reference-based Eviction](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#reference-based-eviction) section).
2. As a tweak to using soft references you can also try a "victim caching approach" as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693511/3255152) which uses a "normal cache that evicts to [a] soft cache, and recovers entries on a miss if possible".
3. If you are certain you want to actually estimate the size of objects then take a look at [Ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/) and its [Sizing Storage Tiers](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.1/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fto-size_sizing_storage_tiers.html%23). It has [Built-In Sizing Computation and Enforcement](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.1/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fco-size_builtin_resizing_computations.html%23) for memory-limited caches.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Guava Cache. I went through the wiki but slightly confuse how can I use Guava Cache in my example? Can you provide an example how would I use it in my case?

Comment: Soft references tend to be an overall negative, because they result in full GCs when over used. That leads to worse performance.